# Xamarin HttpClient.PostAsync task times out in Android, works in iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

This error is all I get.

I have tried to increase timeout as I have seen suggested in other questions, but the same error occurs later instead.

I have checked the Internet permission in the project properties on android.

I have tried in both VS2015 and VS2017. Both Arm and x86 emulators.

Comment: Hey, could you add your code somewhere or something ? It's difficult to help you without knowing what you do exactly :)

Comment: @AntoManiscalco I added ModernHttpClient to the Droid solution. Now it works like magic. :)

Comment: Okay nice, glad you had your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed **ModernHttpClient** in the Android project. I also had to add **System.Net.Requests** to make it build.

Now it works great with no code changes! :)